# Union of affine varieities is a projective variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a subset and let $U_i = \{ [z_0: \cdots :z_n] : z_i \neq 0 \}$ for $0 \leq i \leq n$ be the usual affine cover of projective space.  Suppose that $X \cap U_i$ is an affine variety when considered in $\mathbb{A}^n$ via the standard map $[z_o: \cdots :z_n] \mapsto (z_o/z_i,...,z_n/z_i)$ for all $0 \leq i \leq n$.  Is it true that $X$ itself is then necessarily a projective variety?

Comment: Yes, because  for a subset $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$  being projective is the same as being closed and being closed is a local property of a topological space (=can be checked by intersecting with the elements of any open covering) .