# A subset $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is a projective variety iff its intersections $X_i = X \cap U_i$ are all affine varieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

On page 5 of Harris "Alegbraic Geometry", he writes

> Note in particular that a subset $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is a projective variety if and only if its intersections $X_i = X \cap U_i$ are all affine varieties.

Where $U_i = \{[x_1,\ldots, x_n] \mid x_i \neq 0\}$.

The forward direction is the content of the previous paragraph in the book: if $X$ is a projective variety given by the polynomials $F_\alpha$, then the polynomials $f_\alpha = F_\alpha(z_1,\ldots z_{i-1},1,z_{i+1}, \ldots z_n)$ show $X\cap U_i$ is an affine variety.

For the backwards direction, say $X \cap U_i$ are affine varieties given by $f_{\alpha i}$. I'm guessing you proceed by homogenizing these polynomials to obtain $F_{\alpha i}$ and attempting to show that $X$ is the zero locus, $Y$, of the $F_{\alpha i}$'s. Certainly, every $y \in Y$ is contained in some $U_i$. $y$ satisfies every $F_{\alpha i}$, so after normalizing the $i$th coordinate, it satisfies $f_{\alpha i}$. Then $y \in U_i \cap X$ and therefore $y \in X$. I am having difficulty showing $X \subset Y$. Let $x \in X$. If $x \in U_i$, then the $F_{\alpha i}$'s vanish on $x$ for this fixed $i$ (by construction), but I haven't been able to find a reason why $F_{\alpha i}$ should vanish on $x$ when $x \not \in U_i$. I feel I am missing something very obvious.

Note that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249382/union-of-affine-varieities-is-a-projective-variety) is effectively the same as mine, however the answer (comment) references a fact I am not familiar with. I would prefer a hands-on proof, using polynomials. This statement comes fairly early in the book, so I suspect it should be "obvious".

Comment: I believe we want to do the following. We have $X=\cup_i X_i$, so we don't want $Y$ to be the vanishing of all the $F_{\alpha,i}$'s (that would be like $\cap_i X_i$); we instead want $Y$ to be cut out by the ideal $\cap_i \langle F_{\alpha,i}\rangle$. Then when $x$ vanishes on the $F_{\alpha,i}$'s for a fixed $i$, it will be in $Y$.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need to prove here? That is, do you need to show $X$ is closed, or cut out by polynomials, or irreducible, or ...?

Comment: @KReiser, the definition I am using is that $X$ is a (projective, affine) variety if it is the zero locus of a collection of (homogenous,  - ) polynomials. I would like to prove this directly from the definition.

Comment: @Dave This solves the immediate problem I was having, but (I think) introduces another--I'm now having difficulty showing $Y \subset X$.  My set of polynomials makes the variety too small, and I think yours makes it too big.

Comment: Potential duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059367/closed-subscheme-of-a-projective-scheme-determined-by-homogeneous-ideals/3414596#3414596) - does the answer there make sense to you, or is it too schemey?

Comment: If $X$ is a topological space, then any open cover $X=\bigcup U_i$ is [coherent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_topology#Definition) with $X$. That is, a subset $Z\subset X$ is closed in $X$ if and only if $Z\cap U_i$ is closed in $U_i$, for all $i$. Since the closed subsets of $\mathbb{A}^n(k)$ (resp., of $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$) are the affine (resp., projective) algebraic subsets, it suffices to argue that the maps
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{A}^n(k)&\to U_i=D(x_i)\subset\mathbb{P}^n(k)\\
a&\mapsto(a_1:\cdots:a_{i-1}:1:a_i:\cdots:a_n)
\end{align*}
are homeomorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

This is a response to my comment above, but is too long for a comment.

I'm using my definition of $Y$, i.e. as cut out by the ideal $I:=\cap_i \langle F_{\alpha,i}\rangle$; let $I_i:=\langle F_{\alpha,i}\rangle$. Take $y\in Y$. Then $F(y)=0$ for all $F\in I$. In particular, we have $\prod_i F_i(y)=0$ for all $F_i\in I_i$.

We can argue the following (I leave it to you to check): there must exist an $i$ such that $F_i(y)=0$ for all $F_i\in I_i$. Hint: suppose that, for each $i$, there is $F_i\in I_i$ such that $F_i(y)\neq 0$; what goes wrong?

Thus, with the choice of $i$ above, we have $y$ in the variety cut out by $I_i$, i.e. cut out by the $F_{\alpha,i}$ (for the fixed $i$). This should get you $y\in X_i$ as you want.